Django - Admin – Inline. Add a default value
There is a structure
class StatPersonalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StatPersonal
        fields = "__all__"
    pass

class StatPersonalInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = StatPersonal
    form = StatPersonalForm
    extra = 0

class StatistDaysAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('date_seconds','section')
    inlines = [StatPersonalInline, ]

class StatPersonal(models.Model):
    personal = models.ForeignKey(Personal, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,help_text="",verbose_name="", blank=True, null=True)
    plan = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="", verbose_name="")
    fact = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="", verbose_name="")
    statistDays = models.ForeignKey(StatistDays, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,help_text="", verbose_name="Дневной отчёт", blank=True, null=True)

class Personal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, help_text="", verbose_name="")
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="", verbose_name="")
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

I already have a bundle of user and section. How do I add rows to StatPersonal when adding StatistDays. it is necessary that when creating StatistDays, StatPersonal immediately displays lines depending on users.
if not(request.user.is_superuser):
    sectionUser = SectorToUser.objects.get(user=request.user)
    for pers in Personal.objects.filter(section=sectionUser.section):
        obj.attendance_set.create(personal=pers, plan=pers.count,fact=pers.count) 

